# take screenshot from webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, webpage-screenshot

I want to take screenshot from webpage using JavaScript and include theme the canvas tag.
Previously I tried html2canvas plugin but its not powerful and I want to do this by my self . 
How I can to this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The library you can use https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation

Call this JavaScript File

```
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
    <h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```